# Translate geometry to memoir

Tags: memoir, geometry

How would I go about in translating this geometry to `memoir`?

```
\usepackage[
  paperheight=242mm,
  paperwidth=165mm,
  top=26mm,
  inner=22.5mm,
  outer=22.5mm,
  headheight=10mm,
  headsep=8mm,
  footskip=9mm,
  marginparwidth=17mm,
  marginparsep=2mm,
  height=190mm,
]{geometry}
```

Comment: Note that `geometry` does not support `top=8mm+10mm+8mm`, should be `top=26mm`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This seems to do the trick.

```
\setstocksize{242mm}{165mm}
\settrimmedsize{242mm}{165mm}{*}
\settrims{0pt}{0pt}
\setlrmarginsandblock{22.5mm}{*}{1}
\setulmarginsandblock{26mm}{242mm-190mm-26mm}{*}
\setheadfoot{10mm}{9mm}
\setheaderspaces{8mm}{*}{*}
\setmarginnotes{2mm}{17mm}{5pt}
\checkandfixthelayout
```

Comment: Careful with those calculations, they only work if you have loaded `calc` of which you did not mention. It is probably safer to use `\setulmarginsandblock{26mm}{\dimexpr242mm-190mm-26mm\relax}{*}` (not 100% sure the `\relax` is needed)

Comment: @daleif - `\relax` is used to tell `\dimexpr` to stop parsing.  {...} or [...] will do that as well.

Comment: @JohnKormylo true but that depends on knowing the implementation of `\setulmarginsandblock`  (the `{}` used to delimit the argument do not count)